# Determining intercepts given slope

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

Determine $x$-intercepts of the curve with a slope of $2x+1$ and passes through $(1,-4)$

This is my thoughts:

First I need to find the antiderivative of $2x+1$, which I get to be $\frac{2x^2}{2} + x + C$
or 
$x^2+x+C$.

Then I use $1$ for the $x$ value and I know the $y$ value is $-4$ so:

$$-4 = (1)^2+1+C\implies C = -6$$

So now we know our function is $y = x^2+x-6$

Factor this and find the $x$ intercepts:
$$x^2+x-6 = (x-2)(x+3)$$

Hence
$x = -3$,
$x= 2$

Is my thinking through this problem correct?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your process is absolutely correct and is a good answer, but if you still aren't quite sure, you can always double check the answer by making sure it satisfies the desired properties:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[x^2+x-6\right]=2x+1,\hspace{10mm}\text{and}\hspace{10mm}1^2+1-6=-4$$

as desired, so we definitely have found a curve with the right properties.

Answer (score 0):

here is another way to get there with the fundamental theorem of calculus. you have $$\frac{dy}{dx} = 2x + 1, y = -4 \text { at} x = 1 \to y = -4 + \int_1^x 2t + 1 \, dt = -4 + (t^2 + t)\big|_1^x = x^2 + x -6  $$